# VS Code - Switching Python versions in integrated terminal

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

I have `VS Code v1.44.2` with Microsoft's [`vscode-python`](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) extension installed on `Windows 10` machine.

According to `vscode-python` documentation, it has the ability to set the correct python version in a newly launched integrated terminal window.

That functionality works, sort of: for me, it seems to work only if the Python version picked from the version picker is `3.5.2`--the one that came with Microsoft's ML Server. Also, it works only if the integrated terminal being launched is `cmd`.

When these two narrow conditions are satisfied, sure enough, as soon as you launch the integrated terminal, `vscode-python` runs `/path/to/ML Server/Python/executable/activate.bat` and if you did `python --version` at the command prompt thereafter, you would see:

```
Python 3.5.2 :: Anaconda 4.2.0 (64-bit)
```

Unfortunately, environment activation doesn't work in the case of several other Python version I have installed:`2.7.x`, `3.6.x`, `3.7.x`: not on `cmd` or `gitbash` and I suspect not on many other shells

Looking at `vscode-python` source code, the reason is apparent: `vscode-python` looks for the `activate` script (`activate.bat`, `activate.sh`, `activate`) in the same folder as `python.pythonPath`, whereas these scripts are typically in a subdir of `python.pythonPath/Lib/venv/scripts`.

The relevant code snippet from `vscode-python` repo (`src/client/common/terminal/environmentActivationProviders/baseActivationProvider.ts`) reproduced below:

```
    protected async findScriptFile(pythonPath: string, scriptFileNames: string[]): Promise<string | undefined> {
        const fs = this.serviceContainer.get<IFileSystem>(IFileSystem);
        for (const scriptFileName of scriptFileNames) {
            // Generate scripts are found in the same directory as the interpreter.
            const scriptFile = path.join(path.dirname(pythonPath), scriptFileName);
            const found = await fs.fileExists(scriptFile);
            if (found) {
                return scriptFile;
            }
        }
    }
```

This method is called from `src/client/common/terminal/environmentActivationProviders/bash.ts`:

```
   public async getActivationCommandsForInterpreter(
        pythonPath: string,
        targetShell: TerminalShellType
    ): Promise<string[] | undefined> {
        const scriptFile = await this.findScriptFile(pythonPath, this.getScriptsInOrderOfPreference(targetShell));
        if (!scriptFile) {
            return;
        }
        return [`source ${scriptFile.fileToCommandArgument()}`];
    }

    private getScriptsInOrderOfPreference(targetShell: TerminalShellType): string[] {
        switch (targetShell) {
            case TerminalShellType.wsl:
            case TerminalShellType.ksh:
            case TerminalShellType.zsh:
            case TerminalShellType.gitbash:
            case TerminalShellType.bash: {
                return ['activate.sh', 'activate'];
            }
            case TerminalShellType.tcshell:
            case TerminalShellType.cshell: {
                return ['activate.csh'];
            }
            case TerminalShellType.fish: {
                return ['activate.fish'];
            }
            default: {
                return [];
            }
        }
    }
```

As is evident from these code snippets, if the integrated terminal is `gitbash`, `vscode-python` looks for `activate.sh` or `activate` in `python.pythonPath`, but not in its sub-directories.

My online search for a work around didn't produce much. There are some answers that rely on aliasing or sourcing activate in `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` but that doesn't solve my problem.

Ideally, I would like to have the following functionality:

1. When I set the Python version through VS Code (either command palette or status bar), if there is an integrated terminal open, it should automatically switch version. I suppose the same idea would apply to environments, as opposed to versions.
2. When I launch an integrated terminal, it should launch with the correct version set. I am OK with an automatic call to appropriate `activate` file if required.

I'm sure other `vscode-python` users have run into the same problem, and from the code snippet, the solution appears simple (allow search into `/venv/**/*`); just wanted to see if there might be a different way of achieving my end goals?

Comment: @Code.ie - Not sure if the solution would work for you, but use Wndows command prompt instead of default shell that pops up in VS Code(just type `cmd` there in the intetgrated terminal) and it would work. I had similar sort of issue.  got resolved with CMD

Comment: I am not really sure what you are trying to do, but you can set a venv per folder, per project, per workspace, e.g. as described at https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments That works well for me using Settings - Python: Select interpreter. When I open a new project or folder the old terminal is killed and the new one spawns software using the assigned interpreter.

Comment: @Joe - I have followed the instructions in the link provided but I don't see the behavior you describe: old terminal does not get killed and get replaced by a new terminal. I have tried setting `python.terminal.activateEnvInCurrentTerminal` to `true` in Workspace, User and Folder levels, but to no avail. Only in case of v3.5.2 which comes with Microsoft ML Server does the activation happen automatically and that too only in cmd integrated terminal, as described in the original post.

Comment: @Laxmikant - sure, but that's not my original problem. Switching between windows during development is annoying :)

Comment: Maybe this: conda environments cannot be automatically activated in the integrated terminal if PowerShell is set as the integrated shell. See Integrated terminal - Configuration for how to change the shell. ?

Comment: @Joe - I don't use PowerShell integrated terminal. Looking to make it work through `gitbash`

Comment: @Code.ie -you need not to switch the windows, I have already told you, only type `cmd` in the same window where you are having trouble. Windows will initiate a command prompt in the samw shell.

Comment: @Laxmikant - that doesn't work for me. When I type `cmd` in `gitbash` prompt in integrated terminal, I do get another `cmd` shell in the same integrated terminal, but python version does not sync with the python version for the project. I suspect the sync would not happen till an `activate.bat` run is instigated somehow.

Answer (score 0):

No one answered this?
Here is a link to the setup you should be using.
I'm running MiniConda3 on windows, but you can adjust this for Mac.
I have several environments built for different classes I'm taking for data science. When I open VS Code, the terminal is set to my desired version of Python. CMD prompt. also the correct version is set for either Jupyter or the terminal window.

https://medium.com/analytics-vidhya/efficient-way-to-activate-conda-in-vscode-ef21c4c231f2

Comment: thanks for the link to your article, but my original question didn't have any interest in injecting `conda` (or any variants thereof) into the mix. I have stopped looking for an answer and have learned to live with the limitation